# cout was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and coding entirely. 
When I try to build my code it gives me "error: 'count' was not declared in this scope"
Everything I look up either tells me to add "using namespace std;" or add "int main()" but neither works for me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int A = 4;
    count << &A;
}
```

Comment: In question header it says “cout” but you have count on your code. I think instead of answering this question should be closed since it is nothing to do with stackoverflow. It is simple typo mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your identifier.

`count` should be `cout`.

Also, `main` should have the return type of `int` as it isn't standard C++ to automatically deduce the return type as `int` if not specified. In short, `int main()` is required.

Comment: That was a dumb mistake, thank you. So does making it ```int main ()``` just help it understand?

Comment: @Ohan, it's nothing to do with understanding, `int main` is a requirement of the C++ language. Any program without `int main` is not a valid C++ program.